Trouble understanding 立つ瀬がない
I understand the expression 立つ瀬がない means "having lost face, in a bind", but I have difficulty understanding it’s  practical usage.
For example here, B is A's 後輩, and A put B in a tough situation:

A: ごめん
つらい役目をやらせてごめん
B: 謝らないでほしい
立つ瀬がない

I assume there is some reason why the sight of B's senpai apologizing to her makes B "lose face", but I have struggle understanding the nuance as to why such a thing may be emphasized. Also, is this phrase essentially synonymous to 面目ない?  立つ瀬がない is translated as "losing face", but 立つ瀬 probably means something more like 立場, with 面目ない speaking more directly to "losing face". But I am unsure as to whether that works out to any practical difference in usage. When does one use this phrase?

You can use 立つ瀬がない typically in situations where your role or raison d'etre is questioned or ignored. For example:

You realized that your student was more capable than you
A business deal progressed without your knowledge even though you were supposed to be in charge
You were protected by the person you were hired to protect as a bodyguard

In your situation, "謝らないでほしい、立つ瀬がない" probably suggests that B believes it's naturally his role to be useful to A. If A apologizes like that, it will make B feel his role is questioned for some reason (maybe because B failed to meet A's expectation, or maybe because B is not trusted enough as a partner).
立つ瀬がない doesn't necessarily mean that the person is feeling sorry; it can also be used to express dissatisfaction or frustration.
On the other hand, 面目ない is typically used in situations where someone has done something wrong and feels embarrassed to face others. It's often used interchangeably with "I'm terribly sorry" or "I'm so ashamed". The phrase that contains 面目 and is similar to 立つ瀬がない is 面目が潰れる or 面目を失う.
